# ruby/rails detect financial track data and return nil/empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, credit-card-track-data

I read through similar stackoverflow questions to understand financial track card data.

I think the issue I am facing might be slightly different or maybe I am really weak in regex.

Now we have a service that returns track data accidentally instead of the guest name.

My goal is every time I receive track data I display "" empty string, else return the guest name.( This is a temp solution until we fix the root cause)

This is what my regular expressions is but looks like it doesn't detect track data.

```
irb(main):043:0> guestname="&#x0025;4234242xx12&#x005E;TEST&#x002F;GUEST L      &#x005E;324532635645744646462"

irb(main):044:0> (/[(%[bB])(;)]\d{3,}.{9,}[(^.+^)(=)].+\?.{,2}/.match(guestname)) ? "" : guestname
=> "&#x0025;4234242xx12&#x005E;TEST&#x002F;GUEST L      &#x005E;324532635645744646462"
```

(Not real data)

Now, looking at the wiki for track data information I want to cover most cases, if not all:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe_card#Financial_cards

**Could some help with my regex. This is what I have:**

`/[(%[bB])(;)]\d{3,}.{9,}[(^.+^)(=)].+\?.{,2}`/

> Track 1, Format B:
>
> **Start sentinel** — one character (generally '%')
>
> **Format code="B"** — one character (alpha only)
>
> **Primary account number (PAN)** — up to 19 characters. Usually, but not
>   always, matches the credit card number printed on the front of the
>   card.
>
> **Field Separator** — one character (generally '^')
>
> **Name** — 2 to 26 characters
>
> **Field Separator** — one character (generally '^')
>
> **Expiration date** — four characters in the form YYMM.
>
> **Service code** — three characters
>
> **Discretionary data** — may include Pin Verification Key Indicator (PVKI,
>   1 character), PIN Verification Value (PVV, 4 characters), Card
>   Verification Value or Card Verification Code (CVV or CVC, 3
>   characters)
>
> **End sentinel** — one character (generally '?')
>
> **Longitudinal redundancy check (LRC)** — it is one character and a
>   validity character calculated from other data on the track.
>
> **Track 2**: This format was developed by the banking industry (ABA). This
>   track is written with a 5-bit scheme (4 data bits + 1 parity), which
>   allows for sixteen possible characters, which are the numbers 0-9,
>   plus the six characters  : ; < = > ? . The selection of six
>   punctuation symbols may seem odd, but in fact the sixteen codes simply
>   map to the ASCII range 0x30 through 0x3f, which defines ten digit
>   characters plus those six symbols. The data format is as follows:
>
> **Start sentinel** — one character (generally ';')
>
> **Primary account number (PAN)** — up to 19 characters. Usually, but not
>   always, matches the credit card number printed on the front of the
>   card.
>
> **Separator** — one char (generally '=')
>
> **Expiration date** — four characters in the form YYMM.
>
> **Service code** — three digits. The first digit specifies the interchange
>   rules, the second specifies authorisation processing and the third
>   specifies the range of services
>
> **Discretionary data** — as in track one
>
> **End sentinel** — one character (generally '?')
>
> **Longitudinal redundancy check (LRC)** — it is one character and a
>   validity character calculated from other data on the track. Most
>   reader devices do not return this value when the card is swiped to the
>   presentation layer, and use it only to verify the input internally to
>   the reader.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your example input string does not contain format code after first sentinel.
2. You are trying to parse html-encoded version, which is weird.

So, I would start with html decoding. E.g. with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org):

```
▶ guestname="&#x0025;4234242xx12&#x005E;TEST&#x002F;GUEST L      &#x005E;324532635645744646462"
#⇒ "&#x0025;4234242xx12&#x005E;TEST&#x002F;GUEST L      &#x005E;324532635645744646462"
▶ parsed = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(guestname).text
#⇒ "%4234242xx12^TEST/GUEST L      ^324532635645744646462"
```

OK, now we at least have a leading percent. Now let us ask ourselves: how many users have a guest name starting with a percent sign? I bet none. You might re-check yourself by running a query against your database. Since it is a temporary solution, I would definitely shut the perfectionism up and go with:

```
▶ parsed =~ /\A%/ ? '' : parsed
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what would be the allowed names with the above regex?

Comment: Whatever that is not started with a percent sign.